# Using unlabeled dataset in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, dataset, deep-learning, keras

Usually, when using Keras, the datasets used to train the neural network are labeled.

For example, if I have a 100,000 rows of patients with 12 field per each row, then the last field will indicate if this patient is diabetic or no (0 or 1).
And then after training is finished I can insert a new record and predict if this person is diabetic or no.

But in the case of unlabeled datasets, where I can not label the data due to some reasons, how can I train the neural network to let him know that those are the normal records and any new record that does not match this network will be malicious or not accepted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called one-class learning and is usually done by using autoencoders. You train an autoencoder on the training data to reconstruct the data itself. The labels in this case is the input itself. This will give you a reconstruction error. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder

Now you can define a threshold where the data is benign or not, depending on the reconstruction error. The hope is that the reconstruction of the good data is better than the reconstruction of the bad data.

Edit to answer the question about the difference in performance between supervised and unsupervised learning.

This cannot be said with any certainty, because I have not tried it and I do not know what the final accuracy is going to be. But for a rough estimate supervised learning will perform better on the trained data, because more information is supplied to the algorithm. However if the actual data is quite different to the training data the network will underperform in practice, while the autoencoder tends to deal better with different data. Additionally, per rule of thumb you should have 5000 examples per class to train a neural network reliably, so labeling could take some time. But you will need some data to test anyways.

Comment: Can this be deployed using Keras?
I am developing an Intrusion Detection System where I have huge dataset of normal packets, and I want to train the nn on it in a way that any new incoming packet is to be predicted if normal or malicious. 
But I only have normal packets now.

Comment: Yes, but you have no testdata to see how well your system performs.

Comment: I can divide my dataset into training(70%) and testing (30%), but the think is that all the unsupervised learning using Autoencoder found are on images, I will try to check if there is other ones to use. Thank you :)

Comment: I mean you train on good packages and then test on good and bad packages to see how your algorithm performs.

Comment: Yes that is no problem, one last question, what do you think is better, if I downloaded malicious packets (from DARPA or any other source) and label them, so that I have labeled dataset with normal and malicious packets then train the nn with, or if I use autoencoder for the normal packets I have? @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need fit two different models:

1. a model for bad record detection
2. a model for prediction of a patient's likelihood to be diabetic

For both of these models, you will need to have labels.  For the first model your labels would indicate whether the record is good or bad (malicious) and the second would be whether the patient is diabetic or not.

In order to detect bad records, you may find that simple logistic regression or  SVM performs adequately.

Comment: Hello dear, the thing is that I am developing an intrusion detection system based on deep learning, I have a dataset of normal packets (huge dataset) and I want to train the neural network for it, such that any packet is inserted in the future is to be predicted if normal or malicious. 
Thus I do not have malicious packets now to train the nn on, only I have normal packets.

Comment: I see. Then using an autoencoder as mentioned by @Thomas above is a good option.  Reconstruction error can serve as a proxy for out-of-training-sample (bad) records.